# SQL Server 2000 cannot use CONVERT in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I am using SQL Server 2000. I would like to convert the `datatype` to `varbinary` when the original type of the field is `nvarchar`. I use the query below:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(test, 'basetype')='nvarchar' 
            THEN (CONVERT(varbinary, test)) ELSE 'FAIL' END AS result 
FROM table1
```

Table1 contains only one column "test" with datatype `nvarchar` and "test" contains only one row with value,"abc" .

When I run the above query in Query Analyzer, the result is "abc" but not the `varbinary` value . Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: Sorry, the Title should be "use Convert in CASE statement"

Comment: I think your 'FAIL' should also be casted to varbinary, like this: ELSE (CONVERT(varbinary, 'FAIL'))

Comment: cha: Thank you for your reply. But what if I would like to write something like if the datatype is nvarchar then convert to varbinary else keep the original data type?

Comment: Read MSDN for CASE. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx. The return type of case statement is the highest precedence type (only one). You can't have a mix of two different types